# Python instruction counting

Tags: python, instructions

Is it possible to have some function that increments a counter run upon each instruction within a function, and does some behavior if a number is reached?

To explain, I want to be able to raise an exception if a function ends up taking up past a certain number of bytecode instructions in the virtual machine. So, if someone creates a list comprehension that will make an infinite loop, or creates an infinite while loop, it will force a break out early.

Can this be done in Python?

Comment: This might be of interest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver

Comment: The `dis` module might come handy: http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html

Comment: @gbtimmon It's definitely interesting, but it's not relevant at all.

Comment: @delnan It completely relavent. Trying to programmatically determine infinite loops is incomputable. My point being this is not an effective way of preventing never ending code. It only works by putting draconian limits on the amout of work which can be done in a function, regardless of weather or not that code is doing significant work or not.

Comment: @gbtimmon Yeah, but that's not what we're doing here. We don't analyze the program or otherwise attempts to determine whether it halts at all, we let it run and (attempt to) kill it if it executes more than a certain (finite) number of instructions.

Comment: There are some bytecode-level tricks [one can pull](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/wicked_hack_python_bytecode_tracing.html) but I can't imagine using them for production purposes.  You're better off experimenting with PyPy's sandboxing facilities if you want to write some secure task server.

Comment: @delnan My point is really that all you would be accomplishing is setting a draconian limit on how much work a function can do before 'breaking the rules'. It would not be an effective way to prevent rouge/infinate code, and would hamstring the power of the language if there was case were good code happened to try to use to many byte codes ( The amount of data a function can process now has a hard limit, This is bad and not scalabe.)

Comment: In the case I'm trying to use this, it is not intended to be scalable. I do want a hard limit. I do want any function run under this condition to die if it exceeds a specific instruction count. This isn't for the whole project, just for bits of code where I know that if the instruction count is exceeded, the function needs to raise an exception and get pulled out.

Comment: @gbtimmon I really don't get why this is your point. It's far outside the scope of the question. Nobody's trying to restricted a language as such in how much work it can do (well, some research guys are doing this, but they aren't present so you argue in vain). It's about a specific program. But yes, it's totally an effective way to prevent damage from infinite, or "just" very resource-intense (generating the first 10 million primes is a bounded amount of work, but takes far too long to make sense) programs -- at a cost, as you point out, but that's the inherent trade off.

Comment: @DSM, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you please make your comment into the form of an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: @delnan But bounding a process on rescource use is well understood and can be supplied readily by the OS, since that's what an OS is designed to do. This is a bad approach to this problem, and I fear the poster is trying to cut down a tree with a hammer. Why not open the code in a child thread with an OS backed timeout and well set priorties (real-time, all major OS support it). That is what these functionalities were designed to support and they do it without breaking into the code space of other processes.

Comment: @gbtimmon I'm inclined to agree with that. I take your dropping the halting problem as acknowledgement it's not relevant? ;-) Note though that piggybacking on the OS fails when you want a metric the OS does not support (well or at all), e.g. an application-specific concept such as bytecode instructions executed. Not that this is relevant for this specific question; I only point it out for completeness.

Comment: I need the function that I'm metering to share the same process. Spawning a second process to kill off with a timer isn't an option for the software architecture I'm dealing with-- at least not in the short term.

Comment: @delnan it is relevant at least relevant in my screwed up way of thinking  :). The OS is designed how it is because it CAN'T do what Kelketek is suggesting.

Comment: @gbtimmon Again, nobody including OP is suggesting attacking the halting problem ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it. Usually, the only robust way to do this is to run the untrusted code in a separate process, properly sandboxed.

Consider what happens if the untrusted code acquires some critical resource (e.g. a lock), and then gets killed because it's taking too long. The entire process will deadlock if anyone will try to acquire that same lock.

Comment: OP wants to raise an exception, which would allow any non-broken cleanup code to run. Of course, it would also easily allow swallowing the exception and carrying on. Which just reinforces that this is a hard problem and would likely involve separate processes.

Comment: Sure, it could allow swallowing the exception and carrying on. And if that's detrimental, it's my fault for not accounting for it. If the exception handling code is broken, it should work as normally broken code-- that is, raising its own exceptions, or getting caught in an infinite loop if it makes one, since it won't be inside the instruction counted code.

Comment: Now that I've had a bit more experience under my belt I've come to the conclusion that this answer is correct.